# Writing a sentence about a reason and a result in the past

Tags: grammar

I want to say that since something happened a few months ago, since it happened, I did some action a few times, as a result of the thing that happened.

How should I say that?:

1. Since it had happened, I did the action
2. Since it had happened, I would do the action

I guess that both of my above tries are incorrect :/

Comment: Give us the exact wording of the entire paragraph. Give us the actual sentence and its actual content. You've got both, and still struggle. How are we supposed to not struggle when given neither?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question implies that you want to say that you did or took some action a few times and then stopped taking that action. This requires the  [past perfect progressive tense](http://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/past-perfect-progressive-tense) (ref.: Writing Explained). If that is your intention, the following example may be helpful.

> *Since* [or *After*] *the terrible events of a few months ago, I **had been going** to therapy sessions but they could not help ease my guilty conscience nor banish my nightmares.*

The implication in this example is that while you had been going to therapy sessions, you are no longer doing so.